# vb6 to C#. Open for file as output, freefile

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I have the following code in vb6 -

```vb
dim iFreeFile as integer

iFreeFile = FreeFile
Open tSendFileName For Output As #iFreeFile
```

I need to convert this to C# but I am having difficulty. I was trying to use StreamWriter but came across the issue of not knowing where to write it or how to insert the file since it is not on my computer.

Any ideas on how to convert this code to C#? Thanks

Comment: The name of the file is stored in `tSendFileName` in the original code. Did you try using that variable?

Comment: It is a text file.

I tried to use 
StreamWriter MyStreamwriter = new StreamWriter(tSendFileName) 
but got stuck when wirting the
MyStreamwriter.Writer() part.

Comment: Try showing us the code you have so far. You're on the right tracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to a text file using a streamwriter is pretty straight forward:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tSendFileName)) {
    sw.WriteLine("Some text"); //write text followed by line terminator
    sw.Write("Foo...bar...foo...bar"); //write text without terminator
}
```

Comment: VB6 will write text files using ANSI encoding. A standard .Net stream writer [will use UTF-8 without BOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx). For a precise translation of the VB6, you should specify `Encoding.Default` when you create the StreamWriter. Like this `new StreamWrite(tSendFileName, Encoding.Default)`

Answer (score 0):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);


tw.WriteLine("Creating file in memory.");
tw.WriteLine("Adding extra line.");

// just use savedialog to save file on disk
File.WriteAllBytes(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, ms.GetBuffer());
```